# Hovering jet-pack in rotating Toroidal Colony in presence of air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we create artificial gravity by rotating large ring in space.

Such as this [image]

Source: http://settlement.arc.nasa.gov/70sArtHiRes/70sArt/art.html

I fly a jet-pack and hover above a certain spot , In absence of air I understand that the thrust will provide centripetal force making me fly in circular motion just above the spot in sync

Will this hold true in presence of air for long time so I am still hovering above my initial spot I take off from ???

Comment: A rotating space station does not provide "artificial gravity". It only provides a centrifugal force, but only as long as you are touching the rotating "floor". As soon as you leave the floor, you are in free fall. If you give your jetpack a burst that makes your velocity in the frame of the center of rotation zero, you will be hovering indefinitely without having to use it again to generate any trust. With air, on the other hand, your tangential velocity will slowly increase (as you are feeling a wind), and you will slowly "descend".

Comment: It is unclear to me how this would be non-mainstream.